# Getting Twitter Bootstrap's "Tabs" Javascript to Work on Rails App

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

A javascript problem on a rails app.

Twitter docs keep things very straightforward, however I'm still unable to get tabs to work dynamically (tab switching and dropdown).  I straight up copied their source code and downloaded their javascript and included that in my application.js file on my rails app.  Not sure what I'm missing.

The HTML file:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#.tabs').bind('change', function (e) {
      e.target // activated tab
      e.relatedTarget // previous tab
    })
</script>
<h3>Demo</h3>
<ul class="tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
<li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
<li class="dropdown" data-dropdown="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#fat">@fat</a></li>
  <li><a href="#mdo">@mdo</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
<div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
  <div class="active tab-pane" id="home">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

The Application.js file:

```
// Place your application-specific JavaScript functions and classes here
// This file is automatically included by javascript_include_tag :defaults
$(document).ready(function(){

!function( $ ){

  "use strict"

  function activate ( element, container ) {
    container
      .find('> .active')
      .removeClass('active')
      .find('> .dropdown-menu > .active')
      .removeClass('active')

    element.addClass('active')

    if ( element.parent('.dropdown-menu') ) {
      element.closest('li.dropdown').addClass('active')
    }
  }

  function tab( e ) {
    var $this = $(this)
      , $ul = $this.closest('ul:not(.dropdown-menu)')
      , href = $this.attr('href')
      , previous
      , $href

    if ( /^#\w+/.test(href) ) {
      e.preventDefault()

      if ( $this.parent('li').hasClass('active') ) {
        return
      }

      previous = $ul.find('.active a').last()[0]
      $href = $(href)

      activate($this.parent('li'), $ul)
      activate($href, $href.parent())

      $this.trigger({
        type: 'change'
      , relatedTarget: previous
      })
    }
  }


 /* TABS/PILLS PLUGIN DEFINITION
  * ============================ */

  $.fn.tabs = $.fn.pills = function ( selector ) {
    return this.each(function () {
      $(this).delegate(selector || '.tabs li > a, .pills > li > a', 'click', tab)
    })
  }

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').tabs('ul[data-tabs] li > a, ul[data-pills] > li > a')
  })

}( window.jQuery || window.ender );

});
```

Comment: At a first glance, your first JavaScript code looks incomplete. Have a look at the parentheses.

Comment: Okay, what about aside from that? Because I'm new to javascript.  I changed it up to something else not worthy of posting and filled in the parentheses.  My point is, what part of the instructions am I not following correctly?

Comment: If your javascript is not correct, it will not parse, and thus not work. Which would explain why it doesn't work :) Can you open the javascript console in chrome or firefox? This will clearly show if your javascript contains errors.

Comment: @nathanvda SPOT ON! I did just that and realized a bunch of errors in my scripts and because they were being loaded.  I'll post the answer below.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I fired up the javascript console on Chrome and realized that my scripts weren't being loaded.  This is because on rails, you don't need to include the "public" file in your path to load the javascript; only  is needed.

In addition, in the application.hmtl.erb file,   <%= javascript_include_tag 'bootstrap-dropdown.js' %> must be included as :default does not load these js files.

Answer (score 5):

you don't need the first script (it's included in the documentation as an example only, in case you want more than what comes in the box)

what you do need is a link to the bootstrap stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="your_bootstrap_folder/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and two scripts (assuming you have jquery otherwise include that first):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="your_bootstrap_folder/js/bootstrap-tabs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="your_bootstrap_folder/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
```

and finally the function call

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.tabs').tabs()
    })
</script>
```

that should do the trick.

EDIT: just to make sure you've got the sequence right, here's a full example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>bootstrap tabs test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path_to_bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li data-dropdown="dropdown" class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Secondary link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_jquery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tabs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_bootstrap/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('.tabs').tabs()
        })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmmm, honestly, I'm surprised at how this solution did not work.  Sounds solid.  I just added jQuery-rails, then bundle installed, etc.  Also included the 2 scripts leading from my folder. Included the link to bootstrap as well.

Comment: I've added a full example. Works here :)

Comment: Okay, it's something wrong that I'm doing on my part. The tabs appear, but I can't get them to switch and drop down still.  I followed your directions though. Hmmm.

Comment: Make sure that the value of the id attribute on the divs matches the href attribute on the <li> elments.  E.g. if you have an <li> attribute in the <ul> list that says <li><a href="#next">Next pane</a></li>, then the div for that pane needs to be <div id="next">Here we are</div>.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Each tab needs to be activated individually. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs